# Prestashop out-of-memory CSV import error

Tags: out-of-memory, prestashop-1.6, csv-import

I am getting an out-of-memory error importing my CSV file (more than 33000 lines) in Prestashop 1.6.

Comment: I removed an overly-general tag, tweaked the title and body for a bit more clarity, and removed "thanks" and such, which are implied anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase memory limit.

If You are able to edit **.htaccess** file try to add at the end (.htaccess file is located in the main catalog of Your shop)

> php_value memory_limit 128M *(or more like 256M, 512M etc)*

or in **php.ini** file (You need to make a new file and import to server via FTP to main catalog of Your shop)

> memory_limit = 128M *(or more like 256M, 512M etc)*

Both options strictly depends on hosting provider.

Contact Your provider and ask them to increase memory limit.